# Is it a fallacy (or probably a different term) when someone talks about (often condemns) a certain thing that actually didn't happen

Tags: fallacies

Maybe it's simply something like a lie, but I'm not sure what to call it. It is often being done in the news/politics.

A person condemns a certain thing/behavior that is condemnable/detestable but that thing actually never happened in reality.

For example one might say "We must stop all rape in the Antarctic! It is horrible what's happening there". And some people will fall for the trap because obviously rape is bad...

Comment: ‘We must stop all rape in the Antarctic’ presupposes that there is rape in the Antarctic (in the linguistic sense of *presuppose*). So, two claims are being made: that there is rape in the Antarctic, and that we must stop it. Since the former claim is only a presupposition, people will likely focus on the latter claim, which is explicitly asserted. As soon as they engage with the latter claim – grant it *or* deny it – they buy into the presupposition. So, presuppositions are way of ‘sneaking in’ a claim. This is not a fallacy, strictly speaking, because it’s not an argument.

Comment: I made a minor edit that led to some confusion for me. You may roll this back or edit further. Welcome to this SE!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a fallacy can be involved here, since only arguments can be fallacious and no argument is put forward - the person just makes a mistake (a false judgement) about a matter of fact.

I'm not sure there is a standard term for the type of mistake you have in mind but traditional, Aristotelian-inspired logic had the term, *sophismata extra dictionem*. These were judgements whose fault can be detected only by an examination of the matter concerned. Your examples all fall within this category. I'd like to offer something more specific but if there is such a term it has escaped me.

The examples all involve false presuppositions, as Mark Oxford points out. Whoever makes a false presupposition commits *suppositio falsi*. That might be a useful label.

Answer (score 1):

This is like the classic [loaded question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question): "Did you stop beating your dog?" ... the question only makes sense if we assume that the person we adressed has been beating their dog.

Your "We must stop all rape in the Antarctic! It is horrible what's happening there" is likewise loaded ... maybe call it a 'loaded directive'?